# static IP, but cannot reach the dns

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, static-ip

I'm configuring my IP statically, but I cannot reach the DNS.

I have a static IP, and I can ping my default gateway and any external ips.

In `/etc/resolv.conf`, I've set the content the same as when it's working when set up dynamically with "ifconfig eth0 up" :

```
search def.abcd.ca
nameserver 123.45.6.789
```

But with a static IP, DNS is unreachable.

What could prevent me from having dns to be reachable ?

Comment: 123.45.6.789 is not a valid IPv4 address since they need to be 4 bytes, which is not the case of 789. What do you gain by obfuscating things, especially with invalid values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @RobbieTheK.

NetworkManager needed to be disabled : `systemctl stop NetworkManager`

With network manager disabled, two ways to configure manually a connection :

1- In `/etc/network/interfaces`, then turn on/off the interface with `ifup`/`ifdown`

2- By single commands : `ifconfig eth0...` to add the ip ; `route add ...` to add the default gateway.  And look for the DNS in `/etc/resolv.conf`.

If you want to manually set a connection, with network manager enabled, you need to set "managed=true" in "etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf".

Answer (score 0):

Do you have NetworkManager or network running? try `systemctl status NetworkManager` or `systemctl status network`. If you are using NIS, then `systemctl status ypbind`. Replace `status` with `start` and see if any logs appear in your system logs.

Comment: `systemctl status network-manager` : active. `systemctl status networking` : active,    (I have no `ypbind`).

Comment: Different files for configuring DNS when using NetworkManager see [this link](http://xmodulo.com/disable-network-manager-linux.html)

Comment: I'm trying, not working yet...

Comment: It is only working with network-manager and dhcp.